# Draw, drawed, and drewn

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Is drewn an english word? Can we use it as a past participle of draw?

Comment: Did you find it when you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: @DJClayworth nope, did not.

Comment: Then I think you've answered the question.

Comment: @DJClayworth tbh, I don't believe it is as simple as that! It follows valid morphology; therefore, it should be a word. However, I am having a hard time finding a problem with this word.

Comment: Just because it follows common morphological patterns doesn't mean the word was made that way. There are many ways it could've been formed, and it just wasn't formed that way, hence the absence of the word from any dictionaries.

Comment: The *Oxford English Dictionary* does not list "drewn" at all.

Comment: Voting to close because the question can be answered from a dictionary.

Comment: @DJClayworth can we say drewed, then?

Comment: I refer you to the first comment in this thread.

Comment: @DJClayworth how about the picture was drew by him?

Comment: "Drawed" is a moderately common, though erroneous (per most authorities) past tense of "draw".  ("Drew" is the correct past tense, and "drawn" is the past participle.)  I've never heard/read "drewn".

Comment: @HotLicks lol thnx

Comment: @HotLicks I feel stupid now! Hahaha

Comment: Why is this question important to you? Why should it matter to us? Describing more fully why you want to know this might help someone else become interested. It might also provide clues for what you mean by "valid morphology."

Comment: For giggles, I did a search on a corpus called Early English Books Online, to see if this form appeared in early modern English. I received 2 results for *drewn*. I also received 101,384 results for *drawn*. Take from that what you will.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Thank for your Input. Tbh, one of my students asked me and I was stumped for a second. That said, can you please tell me in what context was drewn written?

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost *Renewal of Trading Office Abroed Attention of euthorised deelers is drewn to peregreph 9B.1[iv] of ECM, in terms of which exporters ere required to epply for renewel of remittence fecilities for their existing treding offices ebroed es well es ...* [Ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22drewn%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)  (Errors occur sometimes.)

Comment: The only thing vaguely well known here is [*The Mystery of Edwin* ***Drood***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mystery_of_Edwin_Drood), and that's a proper noun, not a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be understood that words arrived in the English language through about a hundred different paths -- starting from Latin, French, Italian, Spanish, German, Dutch, Scandinavian, Scottish, or Irish, then often ping-ponging back and forth between Old English dialects, and merging and re-merging with said dialects.  While one can often discern patterns as to how, eg, verbs are "declined", there are few true "rules" -- some verbs fit the patterns very closely, others not so well.  Given the nature of how English developed there is nothing remarkable about this.

Directly addressing the question: "Drawed" is a moderately common, though erroneous (per most authorities) past tense of "draw". ("Drew" is the correct past tense, and "drawn" is the past participle.) I've never heard/read "drewn".  If you look in an "authoritative" online dictionary such as [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/draw) it will list these.

Comment: Nice explanation, but make sure you include the basic answer, not just the explanation of the answer.  Also, since you wrote an answer, I think you should explain to OP how to find an answer on their own using a dictionary.  Walk them through the process of finding possible past participle forms for a given verb.